# Can't access angular(8) instances in JqueryUI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, angular8, resizable

I am using jquery UI resizable
I already added:

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';
```

Resizable also works.

```js
$('.myclass').resizable({
  resize: function (event, ui) {
    var divclass = document.getElementsByClassName('ABC');
    for (var i = 0, n = divclass.length; i < n; ++i) {
      var divid = divclass[i].id;
      console.log(divclass[i].id);
      this.myservice.height(divid, ui.size.height + 'px');
      this.myservice.width(divid, ui.size.width + 'px');
    }
  },
});
```

I can't access the functions `width` and `height` inside the jQuery but I can access outside.
Can anyone help me with this issue? :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What kind of error do you get, what is happening and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by adding "var selfRef = this;" outside the function

```
 var selfRef = this;
  $('.myclass').resizable({
     resize: function (event, ui) {
       var divclass = document.getElementsByClassName('ABC');
       for (var i = 0, n = divclass.length; i < n; ++i) {
          var divid = divclass[i].id;
          console.log(divclass[i].id);
    
       selfRef.myservice.height(divid, ui.size.height + 'px');
       selfRef.myservice.height(divid, ui.size.height + 'px');
        }
      },
  });
```